# Is it possible to debug Flutter/React Native IOS apps on Windows if I have an iPhone?

Tags: ios, windows, react-native, flutter

So, I have an iPhone X and I was wondering if it is possible for me to connect it to my PC to debug Flutter (or React Native) apps.

Thank you in advance,
Brock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]No, you cannot debug it from a windows PC, you need XCode to debug IOS Apps, which is only available for MacOS.

As you can see from the official react-native Documentation.

For futher details you can check the official docs.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device

Comment: The OP is asking specifically about debugging, it is conceivable to build the app on MacOS (for example remotely) then to try debuging it on a local Windows machine.